# Pass the stdout of `git diff --name-only` to an executable file as parameters of the file

Tags: bash

So, there's this executable file called pint (it's part of the Laravel 9 framework). It formats PHP files according to a configurable standard like PSR12.
Anyway, you can pass a list of the files you want to format as the parameters of pint like this:

`pint file1 file2 file3 file4 ...`

If you pass no argument, pint formats all files of the project.

So, what I'm trying to do is that I want pint to format only the files that have changed since the last commit. In other words, I want the output of `git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD` to be passed as parameters of pint in bash shell.

So, this is what I could come up with, but sadly it doesn't work:

`git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD -o /dev/stdout | ./vendor/bin/pint`

Which says: `fatal: /dev/stdout: '/dev/stdout' is outside repository at '/home/user/directory'` and then it proceeds to execute `./vendor/bin/pint` normally as if no argument had been passed.

I suppose I should somehow convert `new line` to `space` before passing it to pint but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` is for piping to standard input, but `pint` expects the filenames to be command-line arguments, not stdin.

Use `$(...)` to substitute the output of a command into the command line.

```
./vendor/bin/pint $(git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD)
```

Note that this won't work if any of the filenames contain whitespace, since the spaces will be treated as filename delimiters.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer but I'll accept your answer after the 10 minute limit. Could you please tell me where I could learn about this kind of things? I mean what kind of keywords should I search for to learn this stuff about bash shell?

Comment: Any shell scripting tutorial should explain how to substitute the output of a command into the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need any reputation to accept the answer, but I still need to wait for 7 minutes before accepting your answer.